# APIs not working after upgrade from DataGridPro to DataGridPremium

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, material-ui, mui-x-data-grid

I'm working in a project where initially we used **[MUI X DataGrid](https://mui.com/x/react-data-grid/)**, but later shifted to **DataGridPro** due to the business logics. Recently, changed the plan (upgraded from **Pro** to **Premium**). After changing the plan there are some side effects. I've faced & facing some weird issues with existing codes. I'm using `"@mui/x-data-grid-premium": "^6.0.2"`

Following APIs (`onPageChange`, `onPageSizeChange`, `rowsPerPageOptions`) were working in the previous plan but not in current plan:

```
...
const [page, setPage] = useState(0);
const [pageSize, setPageSize] = useState(10);

const onPageChange = (changedPage) => {
    setPage(changedPage);
    handlePagination({ max: pageSize, offset: changedPage * pageSize });
};

const onPageSizeChange = (changedSize) => {
    setPageSize(changedSize);
    handlePagination({ max: changedSize, offset: page * changedSize });
};
...

<DataGridPremium
    ...
    experimentalFeatures={{ newEditingApi: true }}
    onPageChange={onPageChange}
    onPageSizeChange={onPageSizeChange}
    page={page}
    pageSize={pageSize}
    pagination
    paginationMode="server"
    rowsPerPageOptions={[10, 20, 30, 50, 100]}
/>
```

As you see from the above code that this is a **server-side** pagination with **controlled state** (`pageSize` & `page`). As i mentioned it was working code earlier but now not working (associated `func` not triggering). In addition, Rows per page dropdown shows [25, 50, 100] instead of [10, 20, 30, 50, 100]. You can have a look at the [DataGridPremium API](https://mui.com/x/api/data-grid/data-grid-premium/). APIs used as per documentation but not working.

---

***Note**: I've faced few days ago similar type API related issues for example row selection not working as expected but later fixed it as per below code:*

```
// from this
onSelectionModelChange={(newSelectionModel) => handleSelections(newSelectionModel)}

// to this
onRowSelectionModelChange={(newSelectionModel) => handleSelections(newSelectionModel)}
```

---

Now coming back to my current problems with the APIs, how can i fix it? Is there anything i missed or need to do? Or it's bug from **MUI X DataGridPremium** end?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The APIs were not working/broken due to version mismatch. Previous APIs are for older version (`v5`). In my case, as the plan is upgraded & installed the latest version (`v6.0.2`) so the APIs should be used the newer ones (as per documentation, *although the documentation illustrates that the newer APIs are for the version `v6.0.3`*). Anyway, below are the changes need to be done to be working

```
...
const [paginationModel, setPaginationModel] = useState({
    page: 0,
    pageSize: 10,
  });

useEffect(() => {
    const { page, pageSize } = paginationModel;
    handlePagination({ max: pageSize, offset: page * pageSize });
  }, [paginationModel]);
...

<DataGridPremium
    ...
    pageSizeOptions={[10, 20, 30, 50, 100]}
    paginationModel={paginationModel}
    onPaginationModelChange={setPaginationModel}
/>
```